# how do I view files on micro sd?

Tags: sd-card, file-system, mount, file-management

I just saved the files from my flip phone to a micro sd card, and put that micro sd card in my android tablet. I went to the file manager, but I didn’t see anything for mounting the sd device, or that it was accessible. where should I look to access files from sd cards?

using Android lollipop

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard location for the sd card directory but look for a folder called external_sd. It will depend on your tablet model.
Perversely, it will not be your /sdcard directory, this folder is your embedded storage.

Comment: I just installed VLC media player, and the directory navigator in that, allowed me to quickly find, the file I was looking for.  But Im totally interested in learning what standard way there is to locate, and navigate around files.

Answer (score 0):

The SD card should mount automatically when installed. To check, go to your settings-> storage and see if there is an SD card listed at the bottom.

Using a file manager, the external storage card is normally accessed through: root -> mnt -> extSdCard